# Backbone view event handlers not getting called

Tags: events, backbone.js

I'm creating a web application with Backbone.js. For one of my views, I have an event bound in `events`:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'text!views/book-view.hbs',
    'views/book-edit-view'
], function(Backbone, Handlebars, bookViewContent, BookEditView) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'book',

        template: Handlebars.compile(bookViewContent),

        events: {
           'click .book-edit-link': 'showEditView'
        },
        // ...
```

In my `showEditView` method, I have an `alert` call, so I would know if it was getting called. However, when I click the element with `.book-edit-link`, it isn't getting called.

book-edit-view.hbs:

```
<strong class="book-title">{{title}}</strong>
<span class="book-author">by {{author}}</span>
<a class="book-edit-link">Edit</a>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<li style="height: 110.571px;" class="book">
    <strong class="book-title">The Martian</strong>
    <span class="book-author">by Andy Weir</span>
    <a class="book-edit-link">Edit</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You're going to want to at least show the HTML that is actually rendered,  There are just too many reasons for a click to get masked.

Comment: Added handlebars template and rendered HTML.

Comment: Fixed the issue. It was a problem in how my collection view was creating individual item views.